# C/C++ Initialize Char Pointer

Tags: c++

I guess I am confused for some reason on how to initialize a char pointer value. Maybe I am overthinking it. I have this in a header file called Login.h
char *arg1;

I got a warning that the member variable is not initialized in this constructor. So in Login.cpp I put:

```
Login::Login() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    arg1 = (char *)malloc(50); 
    //arg1 = new char();
    //arg1 = nullptr;

}
```

What is the difference between:

```
arg1 = (char *)malloc(50);
```

```
arg1 = new char(50);
```

When I try the code below, I get incompatible type.

```
arg1 = 'A';
```

I guess I am confused on initializing a pointer vs a normal variable

Should I just do this?

```
arg1 = nullptr;
```

Hoping someone can clarify this for me, thanks.

Comment: You probably meant new char[50] to allocate 50 characters.

Comment: If you can use `std::string arg1{};` if not then `char *arg1 = new char[50];` (don't forget, you are then responsible for calling `delete[] arg1;` when done with `arg1`)

Comment: So to be clear, new char[50] creates the space for 50 characters? That's how you would initialize a pointer variable and I could assign it an actual value somewhere else when needed?

Comment: Yes you are right I meant char[50]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming `arg1` is interpreted to be a character string, this will make the compiler happy in addition to other goodness:

```
Login::Login() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    arg1 = (char *)malloc(50); 
    arg1[0] = '\0';
}
```

Now `arg1` is a properly null terminated string.  It's essentially an empty string.  Without that `= '\0'` initializer, arg1 was a pointer to allocated, but uninitialized memory.  Originally, before this change, there's was no guarantee of a null terminator within that allocated 50 byte array.  Any attempt to `strcpy`  the contents of that string, would result in undefined behavior as the copy code could pass the array bounds looking for a null char that isn't there.

Two other things to consider.  Why not just declare `arg1` to be of type `char arg1[50]` or of type `std::string arg1`.  Then you don't have to worry about freeing the memory as much and your class's default copy constructor will do the right thing.

Comment: I guess I should provide more context. I am learning secure coding and my task is to find instances of non-secure code. One of the issues in the checklist of issues is member variables not initialized. I understand normal variables and initializing them. (For example bool status; and then I would initialize status = false). Pointers have just thrown me off and it is confusing because of the rest of the code. Here is the .cpp and .h file in question(Login.cpp, Login.h). . It is weird because arg1 is given a string value but that is not on the checklist. https://repl.it/@TomSoyer/SecureCoding

Comment: Was also wondering if it is proper just to initialize pointers to nullptr.

Comment: You can and should initialize a pointer to null.  But if you allocate memory and assign the pointer to that address (via malloc or new), then you have a valid pointer, but the memory contents could be anything.  So it's always a good idea in the context of secure programming to "zero out" the array after obtaining the memory.  And before you free/delete it, do the same.